# How to use collate in a constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, collation

I need to add a constraint to input specific sample data in uppercase to a column named `State` . this is what i tried. but it returns error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLLATE'."

```
ALTER TABLE [Client]
ADD CONSTRAINT [client_statecheck]
CHECK COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS (State in('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC','TAS', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement COLLATION at the column level not while adding constraint.

```
   ALTER TABLE Client ALTER COLUMN State 
                    varchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE [Client]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [client_statecheck]
    CHECK (State in('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC','TAS', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT' ));
```

Comment: the inputs of the column are these only. 'QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC','TAS', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT'.

Answer (score 0):

> COLLATE doesn't work with an IN...

check below link have more info and solutions.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic594604-338-1.aspx